# I have SQL script that loads the data from CSV file to a table. The script uses various procedure and also reads the CSV file from the local path

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

The script is running fine in Oracle SQL developer version 19 whereas in Version 21, the script is unable to locate the local path.

The error I am getting is `delims` was unexpected at this time

Below is the script that is used to read the file from local path

```
host for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b &asig_dir\*.csv') do echo @@&load_asig &asig_dir.\ %f >> &runfile 
host for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b &ugrp_dir\*.csv') do echo @@&load_ugrp &ugrp_dir.\ %f >> &runfile 
host for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b & ngrp_dir\*.csv') do echo @@&load_ngrp &ngrp_dir.\ %f >> &runfile
```

Kindly help me regarding the issue

Comment: `HOST` invokes the subsequent commands in the host operating system. This is not really an SQL or SQL Developer question but a command-line scripting question. What do you get if you use the command line to run `for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /b &asig_dir\*.csv') do echo @@&load_asig&asig_dir.\ %f >> &runfile` (after replacing the substitution value `&asig_dir` with its value)?

Comment: Basically the provided cmd script is embedded inside a sql script. The line reads the file from the local and loads the data into staging invoking the different procedure calls provided in the SQL script